# difference between export default with and without curly brackets

Tags: node.js

```
const obj = {
      key1: 1,
      key2: 2,
      key3: 3
}

export default obj
```

I noticed that this expression

```
export default {key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 3}
```

and this expression has a different effect when imported. What is the exact difference and why does that happen?

Comment: it is not about reactjs. and yes they are exported the same way

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any difference. The object is exported the same way whether its stored in a variable before or written on the same line.